# Can a PWA app be published to app store Swift

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, progressive-web-apps

Is there any way to push these PWA apps to apple store. So my query is whether we have tools for converting the Progressive Web Apps as .ipa files so that we can put them to apple store.

I googled a bit and is right now confused because some say it is possible, some say not possible in Apple store.

Any help on this will be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: pwa not allowed, try to use framework like react native or flutter for develop your application, and then you can use apple's tool to publish your app, if you have a developer.apple account or if you have an access to appstoreConnect website, you can find more description there, best luck

Comment: Have a look at [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Android, TWA support is not available in Apple platforms yet. So for publishing PWA to apple app store, I presume we have to use WKWebView. I could find these two approaches:

1. Hybrid app package: Make a hybrid app using Cordova or Capacitor. These will provide an app wrapper to bundle your app's assets with IPA. But currently, it does not support service workers.
2. PWA launcher: Using WKWebView and AppBoundDomains (recently released, available in iOS14). With this, we can launch the browser app in standalone mode. More info on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LELAuNihs18

Useful links: https://firt.dev/ios-14/#web-views-and-pwas-in-the-appstore

https://www.simicart.com/blog/pwa-app-stores/

https://webkit.org/blog/10882/app-bound-domains/

Answer (score 0):

We used [pwabuilder.com](https://https:/pwabuilder.com) to generate swift projects for our applications.

After some tweaking (mostly oauth flow, cookies and external resource handling), we were able to publish multiple 100% web-based apps to the App Store.

As it is still a regular swift app, there is an ability to add any swift-based components to/instead of any routes (for example, we added native animated loader screens, which are shown while waiting for the SSR to load), as well as to handle notifications.

P.S. we use `bubblewrap` for TWA android build. It requires very little configuration, so we do not care much about reusing non-web codebase across the platforms.